# How to get yesterday's date in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve yesterday's date in my ASP.NET web application using C#.
I've tried searching for a solution but have not had much success. The code I'm using just outputs today's date:

```
string yr = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
string mn = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
string dt = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
date = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", yr, mn, dt);
```

How can I get yesterday's date?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use [DateTime.AddDays()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) method with value of `-1`

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

That will give you : `{6/28/2012 12:00:00 AM}`

You can also use

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
```

That will give you previous date with the current time e.g.  `{6/28/2012 10:30:32 AM}`

Comment: What if you want yesterday up to the last second of the day? 23:59:59?

Comment: @Fandango68 try: `DateTime.Today.AddTicks(-1)`

Answer (score 18):

**The code you posted is wrong.**

You shouldn't make multiple calls to `DateTime.Today`. If you happen to run that code just as the date changes you could get completely wrong results. For example if you ran it on December 31st 2011 you might get "2011-1-1".

Use a single call to `DateTime.Today` then use `ToString` with an appropriate format string to format the date as you desire.

```
string result = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: What is the probability of that happening? 1 out of 31536000 seconds in a non-leap year. That comes to be i (iota).

Comment: It may be a rare bug, but the main point is why write four lines of incorrect code when you can write it correctly in one line?

Comment: My variable type is `DateTime`. What to do then?

Answer (score 6):

You will get yesterday date by this following code snippet.

```
DateTime dtYesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

**You don't need to call `DateTime.Today` multiple times**, just use it single time and format the date object in your desire format.. like that

```
 string result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

OR

```
 string result = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);
```

`DateTime.Now` gives you the *current* date and time.

If your looking to remove the the time element then adding `.Date` constrains it to the date only ie time is `00:00:00`.

Finally `.AddDays(-1)` removes 1 day to give you yesterday.

Comment: Why not to use DateTime.Today ?

Comment: Its what came to mind when tapping out an answer. I can't imaging there being a difference in reality. Plus skim read the question and didn't see DateTime.Today was already being used. The important part id `.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: @ZafarYousafi I thought i'd fire up reflector to see if there was an difference in the implementation of `DateTime.Now.Date` and `DateTime.Today`. Turns out that the `Today` method is just a wrapper and returns `Now.Date`. So if `Today` calls `Now.Date` anyways perhaps the difference is `Today` is less performant; in that it's a 2 step call to get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Any good reason to use DateTime.Now.Date instead of Date.Today ?

Comment: No thats fine. Both returns the same value.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now ; 
string today = dateTime.DayOfWeek.ToString();
string yesterday = dateTime.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek.ToString(); //Fetch day i.e. Mon, Tues
string result = dateTime.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The above snippet will work. It is also advisable to make single instance of DateTime.Now;

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Today` as it implies is todays date and you need to get the Date a day before so you subtract one day using `AddDays(-1)`;

There are sufficient options available in DateTime to get the formatting like `ToShortDateString` depending on your culture and you have no need to concatenate them individually.

Also you can have a desirable format in the `.ToString()` version of the `DateTime` instance